# SVN to GIT migration author's list

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am doing a migration from SVN to GIT. I have created a text file of all the user ids that have committed code to SVN. However some of the users have left the company and so their email address is no longer in the system. Does any one know how to map the missing users to the below format for using with Atlassian’s svn-migration-scripts.jar. Or do I no longer include these users in the authors text file?

```
user101 = user101 &lt;user101@mycompany.com&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you to decide what to do with vanished users. The email address you provide does not need to be an active one, so it is perfectly fine to use a mapping scheme like you did. You could also map non-existent users to a "ghost" user. The only limitation is, that each commit need an author in it't metadata, so there must be something.